# Extended Kalman Filter update step with measurement depending on state

Tags: filter, control, kalman-filter

I want to implement a kalman filter and I am wondering whether to use a linear or extended kalman filter.

My motion model is linear. And the translation between measurement and state is linear, too (H is a simple matrix). My state consists of position and veloxity, my measurement of velocity only:

```
x = (x, y, vx, vy)
z = (vx, vy)

H = [0  0  1  0
     0  0  0  1]
y = z - H*x
```

So far, so good. But I am still confused since my measurement z (the veloctiy) is not just a direct output from a sensor, but is an indirect measurement, computed using a function that takes force and proprioception sensor data as input and additionally the state x (the position x, y) in a nonlinear way and returns a velocity.

```
 z = g( x, force measurement, proprioception measurement)
```

Comment: Hi! I am unsure what you are asking about. h is the function that maps a state to the expected measurement, so of course it cannot depend on the measurement itself.

Comment: You are mixing up the measurement function \$h(x)\$ and the evolution function \$f(x, u)\$.

The residual \$z - h(x)\$ is the difference between the actual measurement, and the expected measurement if the state was known.
If you are indeed measuring velocity, then your measurement function is linear (your expression for \$H\$ would be accurate. You are saying it's nonlinear, so we are missing something here.

Comment: yes I think that is what my confusion is about. So if my evolution function f(x,u) is nonlinear in x, but my measurement function is linear, I can use a linear kalman filter and I don't need the jacobian / EKF?

Comment: The non-extended Kalman filter requires both to be linear.

Comment: I don't see the evolution function f(x,u) included in any equations in literature. Do you think the way to go is just to set z = f(x,u) and use the equations of the linear kalman filter for everything else (even if the optimality is not assured as in the actual linear filter)?

Comment: Literally the first equation on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Kalman_filter#Formulation)

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean evolution function f(x,u), I meant a function z = f(x,z1,z2) so the measurement (velocity) is computed using a function that takes the predicted state and sensor measurments (like force) as input.

Comment: Such a function cannot bea part of a Kalman filter. The measurement outcome only depends on state, never on other/previous measurements. If it did, those would be state too.

Comment: If you want us to help you, you'll need to improve your fundamental understanding of Kalman filters, or be *very* specific about the system you are trying to model.

Comment: I updated my question, is it clear what I'm asking about now?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to implement a kalman filter. My motion model is linear, but the measurement model is nonlinear, so I want to use an extended kalman filter.

If the motion is linear, I would be inclined on using the Linear Kalman filter. From what you said, you have a state \$x\$ and a nonlinear function \$h(x)=z\$ that gives you the measurement \$z\$. If that function \$h\$ is invertible then you will have a design choice to make. You can either model the system as
$$
x_{k+1} = Ax_{k}+Bu_{k}+E\eta_{k} \\
z_{k} = h(Cx_{k}+F\xi_{k})
$$
with the noise affecting the state, and not the measurement. Or as
$$
x_{k+1} = Ax_{k}+Bu_{k}+E\eta_{k} \\
z_{k} = h(Cx_{k})+G\xi_{k}
$$
with the noise affecting the sensor measurement. Where \$E\eta,F\xi,G\xi\$ are noise terms, \$A\$ is the linear dynamics and \$u\$ is the control term.

For the first option, if you do have an inverse for \$h\$ you can apply it to \$z_{k}\$ and linearize the system output, then you can use the Kalman filter. But the second option will not be that simple, and you will have to use the EKF or some other filter. It all comes down to your noise model, do you need it to be Gaussian? Does it have to be added after applying \$h\$ to the state? Or can it be added to the state and then apply \$h\$?

Answer (score 0):

The measurement \$z\$ is whatever comes out of the sensors. If your sensors measure velocity directly, that's fine. AFAICT from your description, this not the case however: for you, \$z\$ is simpy the output from the sensor, nothig else for now.

To relate the sensor's output to the actual state that you are interested in (e.g. velocity or position) we need a model of what the sensor actually measures. This is captured by the function \$h(x)\$. It takes as an input the current state, and outputs the expected measurement (sensor output). By *'expected'* I mean *'in the absence of noise'*.

The Kalman filter's job is now to somehow invert the equation \$z = h(x)\$, such that given the measurement \$z\$, it finds the state \$x\$ that is most likely (also taking into account the previous estimate of \$x\$).

If \$h\$ is nonlinear, the Kalman filter is not applicable. Instead you may get by by linearizing it in every time step, which is precisely what the extended Kalman filter does.